# How do i use my items in my Menu?

Tags: java, android, button, menu, action

I have create a menu in the action bar but I don't know how to use the items inside of it as a button.

That's my menu 'xml' code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_add_circle_outline_black_24dp"
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom">
        <menu>
            <item
            android:id="@+id/deleteMenu"
            android:title="Delete All" />
            <item
            android:id="@+id/exitMenu"
            android:title="Exit" />
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item
    android:id="@+id/addMovieOffline"
    android:title="Offline Mode" />
    <item
    android:id="@+id/addMovieOnline"
    android:title="Online Mode" />  
</menu>
```

That's what i have in java:

```
public class MyMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_main);
    }

    // "Creating" my menu.
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

How I use the items I just declare?
For example the "Exit" option

I think it is the most basic thing although I don't know how to reach the item as a button.. Or its already define it self as a button ?

I would like to get an example and explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using menu item inside the item, which is not the correct way to group item in menu.

Try this xml to generate your menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<group android:id="@+id/my_menu" android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
       android:id="@+id/deleteMenu"
       android:title="Delete All" />
    <item
       android:id="@+id/exitMenu"
       android:title="Exit" />
</group >

<item
    android:id="@+id/addMovieOffline"
    android:title="Offline Mode" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/addMovieOnline"
    android:title="Online Mode" />  
</menu>
```

For receiving events of the click on menu:

```
@override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.item1:
                // action needed
                return true;
            case R.id.item2:
                // action needed
                return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this**

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.exitMenu:
                //Your Logic
                return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use onOptionsItemSelected Method.

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {

        case R.id.exitMenu:

          //code here

           return true;

    }

    return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}
```

Use switch case to identify the ids of menu items.